# Why is my table empty when i print it to an html file?

Tags: html, r, xtable

I have run into some issues with printing tables to html files using R. When I view the file in R, everything looks fine but when I use `print()`, the file becomes empty:

```r
Table_3 <- cbind(City_buildyear, Town_buildyear)
colnames(Table_3) <- c("Storstadsregion (andel)", "Småstadsregion (andel)")
rownames(Table_3) <- c("-1939", "1940-1959", "1960-1979", "1980-1999", "2000-2015")
xtable_3 <- xtable(Table_3, caption = "Samband stadstyp och byggnadsår")
print(x = xtable(xtable_4), type = "html", file = "Table3", digits = 3)
```

[image: An example of how I want the html file to look, and what r previews]

I've tried some different code but none seem to do the trick. I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work. All of my other tables have worked out perfectly fine.

Comment: In your code, you are trying to print `xtable(xtable_4)` instead of `xtable_3`. A typo?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my bad. But I fixed that and changed it to xtable_3 which unfortunately didn't fix it... But thanks anyway!

Comment: I now managed it to work by simply changing                                                   
print(x = xtable(xtable_4), type = "html", file = "Table3", digits = 3) to                         print(x = xtable(xtable_4), type = "html", file = "Table3.html", digits = 3)